# how to use command to remove spring roo from project

Tags: spring, spring-roo

In the "Chapter 6. Removing Roo" of spring roo doc, there are three steps to remove Spring Roo from project:

Step 1: Push-In Refactor

Step 2: Annotation Source Code Removal

Step 3: Annotation JAR Removal

But this solution needs to import the project into Eclipse or SpringSource Tool Suite, then use UI to remove Roo. Is there any commands to remove Spring Roo from project directly?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh

Comment: I was wondering the same thing myself. Roo claims to be easy to remove, but requires you to install eclipse and a whole load of plugins to do it? Maybe Roo is not my thing either. http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/06/11/why-spring-roo-is-not-my-thing/

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any command to remove Roo.

Note steps to remove Roo don't imply you must use STS to do them, you can push-in code and remove annotations by hand, using bash scripts, etc.

Comment: Can you give some guide on how to use scripts to move *.aj into target *.java (that is what push-in doing i think)?

Comment: Sorry, I do it as needed, I haven't saved any doc about it